# How do I move multiple parameter via Move semantics?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Let us assume I have an Object MeasurementValues, which has n different pointers (this examples just show pointers to primitive types, but pointers to other complex objects mivght occur as well).

```
class MesaurementValues {
   private:
     int *measurement_1;
     double *measurement_2;
     long long *measurement_3;
     //..
     float *measurement_n;

     int noPointer;
}
```

I know, this example might be a little bit contrived, anyway. I try to fullfill the [Rule of Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) in my code.

Do I have to

```
this.measurement_x = old.measurement_x ;// for all x = {1,..,n} ?
```

Comment: Start by defining your destructor. This forces you to understand what your class actually means. Then just make it so that all constructors set up the object in such a way that the destructor makes sense. (In *most* classes, the destructor should either be empty, or the class should do nothing else except one specific thing that the destructor handles.)

Comment: Move semantics is an "optimization" over copy semantics. So, the question is how your copy constructor and operator= look like.

Comment: What does the copy constructor do? If it just performs an assignment for "1,..,n", then you shouldn't be writing it anyway.

Comment: Does the class _own_ the objects that the pointers point to? In other words, as KerrekSB says, do you expect the destructor to delete them when the class is destroyed? Once you have an idea of ownership, then you can better understand how to fulfill the Rule of Five. Personally, I prefer the [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

Comment: @Ralf Wickum. When you come to any conclusion, let us know and if any of the answers satifsy your question, be so courteous as to mark it.

Answer (score 1):

First off just be aware that move-semantics give no advantage over copy-semantics for plain-old-data type (POD) members, but it sure does when your class contains other class objects and/or arrays. When you implement move-semantics, it means you have a "move constructor" and/or a "move assignment operator" which would look like this in your class:

```
class MesaurementValues { private:
     int *measurement_1;
     double *measurement_2;
     long long *measurement_3;
     //..
     float *measurement_n;

     int noPointer; 

     //a couple different objects
     someObject*       pObj1;
     differentObject*  pObj2;

 public:
  MeasurementValues( MeasurementValues&& move );  //move-constructor
  MeasurementValues& operator= (MeasurementValues&& move); //move-assignment
}
```

-Assuming your class has POD data and class objects, and
-assuming there are alot of variables to move over:

```
MeasurementValues::MeasurementValues( MeasurementValues&& old) {
    //copy plain-old-data over
    measurement_1 = old.measurement_1;
    measurement_2 = old.measurement_2;

    //copy over values of the pointers
    pObj1 = old.pObj1;
    pObj2 = old.pObj2;
}
```

Keep in mind that move-semantics, as other posters have said, only have an advantage if your data members are other *moveable* objects, or dynamically-allocated memory.

EDIT:

pointers in  must become "invalid", as they've been moved. Therefore I would set them to null to prevent unexpected behavior:

```
MeasurementValues::MeasurementValues( MeasurementValues&& old) 
: measurement_1() //null...
  //,...
{
  //Swapping null into old...
  std::swap(measurement_1, old.measurement_1);
  //...
}
```

Comment: "be aware that move-semantics give no advantage over copy-semantics for plain-old-data type (POD) members" you are right, many people think that move will always be better than copy which is a misconception.

Comment: Thank you for the edit: yes, it is always a good idea to do so. Your example using the pImpl idiom is better in my opinion because you'll never have to worry about having to zero-out pointers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Do I have to
this.measurement_x = old.measurement_x ;// for all x = {1,..,n} ?
```

I would rely on the pimpl idiom for this, and use something like a unique pointer. Below is a detailed example. Note you only have to work with Impl, and rely on its defaults (as it contains no pointers).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Moveable
{
  public:
    Moveable();
    ~Moveable();

    Moveable(const Moveable& m);
    Moveable& operator=(const Moveable& m);

    Moveable(Moveable&& m);
    Moveable& operator=(Moveable&& m);

    int foo() const;


  private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl_;
};

//Moveable.cpp
struct Moveable::Impl
{
  Impl(): a(1), b(2), c(3), buffer(){}
  int a, b, c;
  char buffer[10000]; //Make it worth our while...
};

int Moveable::foo() const{ return pimpl_->a+pimpl_->b+pimpl_->c;}

Moveable::Moveable()
: pimpl_(new Impl)
{
  std::cout << "Default " << (void*)this << std::endl;
}

Moveable::~Moveable()
{
  std::cout << "Destruct " << (void*)this << std::endl;
  //automagically...
}

Moveable::Moveable(const Moveable&m)
: pimpl_(new Impl(*m.pimpl_))
{
  std::cout << "Copying " << &m << " to " << (void*)this << std::endl;
}

Moveable& Moveable::operator=(const Moveable& m)
{
  std::cout << "Copy assign " << (void*)&m << " to " << (void*)this << std::endl;
  *pimpl_ = *m.pimpl_; //Relying on their defaults...
}

Moveable::Moveable(Moveable&& m)
: pimpl_(move(m.pimpl_))
{
  std::cout << "Moving " << (void*)&m << " to " << (void*)this << std::endl;
}

Moveable& Moveable::operator=(Moveable&& m)
{
  pimpl_ = move(m.pimpl_);
  std::cout << "Move assigning " << &m << " to " << (void*)this << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
  Moveable x;
  Moveable y(x); //Copying...
  y = x; //Copying assign

  y = Moveable(); //Default construct, then move assignment, destruct temp
  Moveable z(std::move(y));
  std::cout << "Calling foo " << z.foo() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good example; I think pImpl is definitely a technique all c++ programmers should invest time to learn. If you thoroughly understand the above example, you should have a pretty good understanding of lvalues and rvalues.